# MariaDB server is down but I can still login with mysql client (?)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB 10.3.8, Ubuntu 18 LTS.

When I check for the database status, I see that MariaDB is down. But I can login using the mysql client command.  Is something wrong? How could I debug this?

```
sudo service mariadb status

mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.8 database server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
└─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2019-02-13 08:43:11 IST; 1min 0s ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Process: 3293 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 3712 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 3706 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 3693 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3878 (mysqld)
Tasks: 13 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
└─3878 /usr/sbin/mysqld


# lsof -i:3306
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  2346 user_running_mariadb   31u  IPv6  28910      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)


ps uax | grep mysql
root      2049  0.0  0.0   4628  1812 ?        S    08:40   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
user_running_mariadb   2346  0.1  0.4 3005364 114444 ?      Sl   08:40   0:02 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/my_db_files_dir --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=user_running_mariadb    --skip-log-error --pid-file=/my_db_rundir/run/mysqld.pid --socket=/my_db_rundir/run/mysqld.sock --port=3306


#/my_db_rundir/run# ls -l
-rw-rw---- 1 user_running_mariadb group_running_mariadb 5 Feb 13 08:40 mysqld.pid
srwxrwxrwx 1 user_running_mariadb group_running_mariadb 0 Feb 13 08:40 mysqld.sock
#/my_db_rundir/run# cat mysqld.pid
2346
```

I can login:

```
 mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 145
Server version: 10.3.8-MariaDB-1:10.3.8+maria~bionic-log mariadb.org
inary distribution
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input 
tatement.
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Additional outputs:

Error log:

```
2019-02-13  8:52:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2019-02-13  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2019-02-13  8:52:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
2019-02-13  8:52:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
2019-02-13  8:52:13 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
```

journalctl -u mariadb.service

```
Feb 13 08:51:31 my_host systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 13 08:52:13 my_host systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 13 08:52:13 my_host systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 13 08:52:13 my_host systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.8 database server.
```

Answer (score 0):

The service is timed out ('Result: timeout'), and the service has the systemd configuration `SendSIGKILL=no`, which means systemd has just let mysqld continue running.

Why it time out? take a look at `journalctl -u mariadb.service`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added this output to the question.. It can't open ibdata1 from the error.log msg. Not sure why.

Comment: Might of been a long database recovery period. Bit hard to read logs in a comment. The 90 second interval is the default system timeout. More recent mariadb versions (in 10.3) signal extending the timeout which should work with the Ubuntu systemd version.

Comment: The resource unavailable error is when you've attempted to start a second service where the previous one existed. You could type `SHUTDOWN` from the mysql prompt and then restart the service.

Comment: After reboot, I see two running processes as shown on my question (mysqld and mhysql_safe). If I kill mysqld, then I can start Mariadb and it comes up. However, I'm not sure why it doesn't come up after reboot. When mariadb comes up (runnig), ps uax shows 'only one entry for /usr/sbin/mysqld' and it doesn't show mysql_safe.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue, however I'm not completely sure about the root cause and what really fixed the issue. Still, perhaps this information helps others facing the same issue.

1. Reinstalled MariaDB and upgraded to  10.3.12. This wasn't probably needed because I kept hitting the same issue after the upgrade.
2. After reboot, noticed that msyqld status showed as active while mariadb as inactive:

   /ati/mariadb/logs# sudo service mysql status
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated)
   Active: active (running)
   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   Process: 1650 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Tasks: 39 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
   ─2003 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
   ─2301 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr...
   └─2302 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error

   sudo service mariadb status
   mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.12 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
   └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
3. In MariaDB web site, found the way of [enabling mariadb service](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/), with

   systemctl enable mariadb
4. Now, it works again.

Comment: I see part of your troubles here - /etc/init.d/mysql exist. This is a bug. Just delete it. This is the only thing that causes mysqld_safe to run. I've been fighting up hill to get these fixed MDEV-15526 / MDEV-10797.

Comment: @danblack : Deleting /etc/init.d/mysql  solved my problem.   The issue I described in this ticket was happening in a different server , then on the one I reported the issue, and after removing this file, MariaDB came up without issues.  Thanks!